# Synonym request: [port-forwarding] -> [networking]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Can we add [port-forwarding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/port-forwarding) as a synonym for [networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) please?

Currently [port-forwarding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/port-forwarding) has four questions on it, all of which would be perfectly suited under [networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking).

Answer (score 2):

Given the lack of a community agreement to do so (as evinced by both tags still being present), I think we can consider this declined.

This answer is here to stop Community from ever bumping this question again. Upvote it please.

Comment: We could just go through and remove the port forwarding tag from the questions that use it, and put networking in it's place. (Noone will ever know ;) )